# What does send() and recv() return? Not getting full message, always limited to one byte/8 characters?

Tags: c, sockets, send, sizeof, recv

I'm doing a simple socket example in C on ubuntu linux. I know that the `send()` and `recv()` function don't necessarily wait to send/receive the whole message. I'm trying to send a simple hello world message. I know the size of it (at least I think I do), so I'm wondering what I could add to my `send()` and `recv()` implementation to wait for a known message size.

Reading the man page for `send()` and `recv()` says the function prototype looks like this : `ssize_t send(int sockfd, const void* buf, size_t len, int flags)` and recv() uses the same prototype. My question is what do they return - number of bytes or number of characters? Either way why is it always 8?

When testing the size of my message the sizeof() operator is always returning 8 whether I use `char* message = "test";` or `char* message = "Hello world, I clearly do not understand what is going on here";`

**client code**

```
  fprintf(stdout, "client connected to %s:%d\n", hostname, portno);
  printf("Size of %s is : %lu\n", message, sizeof(message));
  printf("other size of %s is %lu, message, sizeof(message)/sizeof(char));
  ssize_t written_bytes = send(socket_fd, message, sizeof(message),0);
  assert(written_bytes == sizeof(message)); //Shouldn't the code fail here?
  printf("written bytes: %lu\n", written_bytes);
```

I would add the server code, but there's no point in wondering why it's not receiving everything if it is never sending it.

Comment: `sizeof(char *)` is always the size of a pointer to `char`, regardless of the size of what it points to. You're probably on a 64 bit system where pointers are 8 bytes long. You need to use `strlen()` instead.

Comment: -_- right. Dumb mistake, thanks!

Comment: Just as an addition, after reading the string via send() you probably don't want to use strlen directly. send() isn't guaranteed to have written a null character to the character buffer in any given call (e.g., the string may be split across packets so you may not see it until a second call to send() ). This would cause bad behavior on the part of strlen() so you just want to look at the number of bytes returned as the length of that string given that call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`send` and `recv` returns *number of bytes* sent and received respectively. When you are testing the size of your message with `sizeof` operator then you are actually calculating the size of pointer which is `8` bytes on your machine.